# Draw huge route in Android Google Maps Activity

Tags: android, sqlite, google-maps, routes, polyline

I have a `gpx` file which has around 20000 lats and longs in it for a longer hiking route. I'm creating an application where I would like to have a google maps activity which always shows this route when it is being opened. I parsed these lats and longs into an `sqlite` database so far and tried to make this route drawn using `polylines`. But the problem is that it is freezing out. I tried to make the data smaller by filtering out and having only every 50th coordinate in the db, like that it works but the problem is that the route is not that correct and also the map activity opens super slow and is being choppy. 
I have seen applications with map, where if I opened them up the map activity opened quickly, showing immediately very long routes on them so I know there must be a solution, but unfortunately I could not find anything that could help me, and I have completely no ides.
I very welcome any ideas and thank in advance any kind of help.

Here is what I did until now:
The db has 3 columns on 1 table caled route: _id, LATITUDE, LONGITUDE

OpenHelper Activity, it uses a premade sqlite db and copies it to the correct place:

```
public class RouteOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "route.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private final Context myContext;

    public static final String TABLE_ROUTE = "route";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_LAT = "LATITUDE";
    public static final String COLUMN_LONG = "LONGITUDE";

    public SQLiteDatabase database;


    public RouteOpenHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.myContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        Log.i("ROUTECREATE", "Database has been upgraded from " + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion);
    }

    public void openDatabase() {
        String dbPatch = myContext.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).getPath();
        if (database != null && database.isOpen()) {
            return;
        }
        database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbPatch, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }

    public void closeDatabase() {
        if (database != null) {
            database.close();
        }
    }

    public void createDatabase() {
        createDB();
    }

    private void createDB() {
        boolean dbExist = DBExists();

        if (!dbExist) {
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            copyDBFromResource();
        }
    }

    private boolean DBExists() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = null;
        String Path = myContext.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).getPath();

        try {
            String databasePath = Path;
            db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(databasePath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
            db.setLocale(Locale.getDefault());
            db.setLockingEnabled(true);
            db.setVersion(1);
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            Log.e("SqlHelper", "database not found");
        }

        if (db != null) {
            db.close();
        }
        return db != null ? true : false;
    }

    private void copyDBFromResource() {
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        OutputStream outStream = null;
        String Path = myContext.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).getPath();
        String dbFilePath = Path;


        try {
            inputStream = myContext.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);
            outStream = new FileOutputStream(dbFilePath);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                outStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }

            outStream.flush();
            outStream.close();
            inputStream.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error("Problem copying database from resource file.");
        }

    }
}
```

Parcelable Activity:

```
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

public class RouteItem implements Parcelable {
private long id;
private double latitude;
private double longitude;

public RouteItem(){

}

public RouteItem(Parcel in) {

    id = in.readLong();
    latitude = in.readDouble();
    longitude = in.readDouble();
}

public long getID() {
    return id;
}
public void setID(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public double getLatitude() {
    return latitude;
}
public void setLatitude(double latitude) {
    this.latitude = latitude;
}

public double getLongitude() {
    return longitude;
}
public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
    this.longitude = longitude;
}

public LatLng getLatLng(){
    LatLng latLng=new LatLng(latitude,longitude);
    return latLng;
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeLong(id);
    dest.writeDouble(latitude);
    dest.writeDouble(longitude);
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<RouteItem> CREATOR=
        new Parcelable.Creator<RouteItem>(){
            @Override
            public RouteItem createFromParcel(Parcel source){
                return new RouteItem(source);
            }

            @Override
            public RouteItem[] newArray(int size){
                return new RouteItem[size];
            }
        };
}
```

DataSource class which has the query in it:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class RouteDataSource {

    SQLiteOpenHelper dbhelper;
    SQLiteDatabase database;

    String[] allColumns={
            RouteOpenHelper.COLUMN_ID,
            RouteOpenHelper.COLUMN_LAT,
            RouteOpenHelper.COLUMN_LONG
    };

    public RouteDataSource(Context context){
        dbhelper=new RouteOpenHelper(context);
    }

    public void open(){
        database=dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void close(){
        dbhelper.close();
    }


    public List<RouteItem> showRoute(){
        List<RouteItem> listRoute = new ArrayList<RouteItem>();

        Cursor cursor=database.query(RouteOpenHelper.TABLE_ROUTE, allColumns, null, null, null, null, null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()){
            RouteItem tracks = cursorToTrackPoints(cursor);
            listRoute.add(tracks);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        cursor.close();
        return listRoute;
    }


    private RouteItem cursorToTrackPoints(Cursor cursor){
        RouteItem entry=new RouteItem();
        entry.setID(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(RouteOpenHelper.COLUMN_ID)));
        entry.setLatitude(cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(RouteOpenHelper.COLUMN_LAT)));
        entry.setLongitude(cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(RouteOpenHelper.COLUMN_LONG)));
        return entry;
    }
}
```

And Map Activity where I draw the polylines:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    boolean mShowMap;
    RouteDataSource rDataSource;
    ArrayList<LatLng> arrayPoints = null;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

        int width=dm.widthPixels;
        int heigth=dm.heightPixels;

        getWindow().setLayout((int) (width * .9), (int) (heigth * .9));

        arrayPoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

        rDataSource= new RouteDataSource(this);
        rDataSource.open();

        mShowMap = GooglePlayServiceUtility.isPlayServiceAvailable(this) && initMap();


        drawMarkerLine();
    }

private boolean initMap() {
        if (mMap == null) {
            SupportMapFragment mapFrag = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mMap = mapFrag.getMap();
        }
        return (mMap != null);
    }

private void drawMarkerLine(){

        List<RouteItem> rEntries = rDataSource.showRoute();

        for (RouteItem m : rEntries){
            PolylineOptions options = new PolylineOptions();
            options.color(Color.RED);
            arrayPoints.add(m.getLatLng());
            options.addAll(arrayPoints);

            mMap.addPolyline(options);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us your progress by pasting your code here.

Comment: Hi kopikaokao, I added all my current codes to the post.